# jQuery animate gets resolved immediately

Tags: jquery, coffeescript, promise

I have several animations in jQuery and want to run function when they all are complete. I create promise object and put it in a "promises bucket". Unfortunately, my animation is getting resolved straight away. Is there something missing in the code? I get message printed to console way before 5 seconds that it should take.

Code in CoffeeScript

```
animBucket = []
animBucket.push $('#a').animate({opacity: 0.5}, 5000).promise()
animBucket.push $('#b').animate({opacity: 0.5}, 5000).promise()
$.when animBucket
  .then () ->
    console.log 'All animation done'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to `.apply` when using `$.when` on an array:

```
$.when.apply null, animBucket
    .then () ->
        console.log "all done"
```

Otherwise, `$.when` is treating the array as a single resolved value. Calling `.apply` converts the input from an array to varargs.

Comment: On an unrelated note, posting an answer from a phone is quite painful :) I hope I helped.

Comment: Shouldn't `$.when.apply null, animBucket` be `$.when.apply $, animBucket` if you want the same effect as called `$.when()`?  I know you get away with passing `null` here (it happens to work), but that is only because the implementation chooses not to use `this` which isn't something you can ncessarily count on.

Comment: $ is used as a namespace in jQuery so I find `null` more concise. However like you said both work

Comment: Hmmm, you find `null` more concise than `$`?  And, just because it's a namespace doesn't mean that a method on it couldn't reference `this`.  That's an implementor's choice and because the jQuery namespace can have its name changed, there could even be a reason for using `this`.

Comment: @jfriend00 lexical typing doesn't work like this :) (Even if the namespace is changed, the name the components use internally are closed over). To address your concern - in particular the jQuery library makes a _guarantee_ that everything that is under `$` does not use `this` _at all_ and anything under `$.fn` uses `this`. Other libraries might vary in this, so it's good that you noted that.

Comment: Yeah, I know it's not an issue with `$.when()` specifically, but it seems a bad habit to be in or to promote.  Why not just pass `$` to the `.apply() so the call ends up identical to a `$.when(p1, p2, p3)` call and just be in that general habit?  Just curious why you wouldn't want to just use that practice?